# add some Parameter to all swagger request in l5-swagger

Tags: php, laravel, annotations, swagger

I have some Parameters that I should write for every swagger request Annotations.
for example :

```
 *      @OA\Parameter(
 *          name="Content-Type",
 *          in="header",
 *          required=true,
 *          example="application/json",
 *          @OA\Schema(
 *              type="string"
 *          )
 *      ),
```

is there any way that I write these Parameters somewhere else and add them to all swagger annotations?